# Routes with different handler in web api asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

Hi people I need help about a problem with routes and handler in web api. I have two routes, I want that one route uses a custom handler, the other routes uses default. I have this code.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(

            name: "NamedActions",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            handler: customConfig.MessageHandlers.Add(new BasicHandler(new Repository()))
        );

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiLogin",
            routeTemplate: "apiLogin/v1/LoginApi",
            defaults: new { controller = "LoginApi"}//,
        );
```

but when I put `handler: customConfig.MessageHandlers.Add(new BasicHandler(new Repository()))` that throw me an error (*Error   43  The best overload for 'MapHttpRoute' does not have a parameter named 'handler'*).

I want the first route uses the handler `BasicHandler()` with the `Repository()`, the other one without this custom handler. Is this possible, have two routes with different handler?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem, I miss an attributte in `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` , if I want to put the attribute handler, I must to put the attribute constraint first and later the handler attribute. for example:

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(

```
        name: "NamedActions",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraint: null,
        handler: customConfig.MessageHandlers.Add(new BasicHandler(new Repository()))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible, have two routes with different handler

no ! you should use attribute routing

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes